# C# HTTP Status Code Ranges .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, enums, .net-3.5

I'm working with an analytics API that responds in 3 status codes:

```
200: Successfully ingested

400: Missing Parameter

50x: Server Error
```

I would like to encapsulate these statuses within a readable enum, but handling the 50x would require a range of values of which enums do not support.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this kind of scenario?

Comment: what do you mean enum can't handle them?

Comment: I think he wants one enum value to cover all of the 50x responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I wasn't able to find a way to directly support a range of values for a specific enum I did come up with a possible solution.

An extension method you can use to parse all codes between 500 and 599 and return a single AllServerErrors value.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    namespace UnitTestProject35
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestSuccessParse()
            {
                HttpResponseCode parsedHttpCode = HttpResponseCode.Unknown;
                parsedHttpCode.TryParse(200, out parsedHttpCode);

                Assert.AreEqual(parsedHttpCode, HttpResponseCode.Success);
            }

            [TestMethod]
            public void TestServerErrorParse()
            {
                HttpResponseCode parsedHttpCode = HttpResponseCode.Unknown;
                parsedHttpCode.TryParse(500, out parsedHttpCode);

                Assert.AreEqual(parsedHttpCode, HttpResponseCode.AllServerErrors);
            }                
        }

        public enum HttpResponseCode
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Success = 200,
            MissingParameter = 400,
            //etc...

            AllServerErrors = -1,
            InternalServerError = 500,
            NotImplemented = 501,
            BadGateway = 502,
            //etc..        
        }

        public static class EnumExtensions
        {
            public static void TryParse(this HttpResponseCode theEnum, int code, out HttpResponseCode result)
            {
                if (code >= 500 && code <= 599)
                {
                    result = HttpResponseCode.AllServerErrors;                
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (HttpResponseCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(HttpResponseCode), code.ToString());
                }                                        
            }
        }
    }
```